# Can't connect to Heroku Postgres database from Homestead Vagrant box

Tags: postgresql, heroku, vagrant, homestead, heroku-cli

I'm trying to connect to Heroku postgres database from my local. I'm running a Laravel Homestead Vagrant box `"laravel/homestead": "v2.2.1"`

I'm using the CLI from inside a vagrant ssh login

I can get the info like this:

```
$ heroku pg:info
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 0/20
PG Version:  9.6.4
Created:     2017-09-12 05:22 UTC
Data Size:   7.1 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
Add-on:      {Add-on name}
```

but can't connect e.g.

```
$ heroku pg:psql
--> Connecting to {Add-on name}
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "ec2-184-72-245-58.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (184.72.245.58) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Update: Have also tried to connect from outside the vagrant ssh login, just running CLI via Terminal from the local directory in OSX. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The 5432 port in our office was blocked.